# ASP.NET Core Access User.Identity in Controller Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a scenario where I need to access `User.Identity` Claims in my Constructor's Controller.

I need this because the Claims have information required for me to spin up a custom DB Context (Connection String)

How can I go about accessing this? I would just inject in the DBContext, but based on the user, they may need to access a different DB.

Is there a better way to think about this?

```
[Authorize]
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    public DefaultController()
    {
        // this is NULL
        var authenticatedUser = User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: SHow us a smaple code of the class that need it.

Comment: I just need to access User.Identity in a Controller Constructor.

Comment: You should show us what you've tried then we modify the sample there to help you know how to access to the data you're looking for.

Comment: Accessing the `User` in the controller constructor will always be null. Nothing else you can do about it. Try using an `ActionFilter`.

Answer (score 32):

As of version 2.1 of ASP.NET Core, `HttpContextAccessor` is provided. For this we must follow the following steps:

Configure the service using the standard implementation in the `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Perform the dependency injection of `IHttpContextAccessor` on the controllers. Use `HttpContext` property for access to `User`

```
[Authorize]
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    public DefaultController(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        // Here HttpContext is not Null :)
        var authenticatedUser = contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct but User is still null.

Comment: You have to check if you have the right configuration in Startup, this works for me

Comment: I did this, but my IIS config was incorrect, doing this fixed it. You can open IIS and: 1-Activate Windows Autentication; 2-Disable Anonymous Autentication. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737989/httpcontextaccessor-httpcontext-user-identity-name-is-empty-in-iis-working-in-v)

Answer (score 1):

From Rabea AlTaradeh above link:

```
    Startup.cs
     //services section
     services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  #region DI         
  private string UserEmail;
  private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
  public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
  {
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    UserEmail = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "preferred_username")?.Value;

  }
  #endregion DI 
   public IActionResult Index()
   {            
      ViewBag.UserEmail = UserEmail;   
      return View();
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm using asp net core 2.2

Answer (score 0):

```
 This code I using to get the calims

 --------

      int user_id = 0;
      int Account_id = 0;
      List<string> roles;

    public TEMP_CON_Controller(DatabaseContext context,IHttpContextAccessor,httpContextAccessor)
    {
      _context = context;
      if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        var user = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;

        this.user_id = int.Parse(user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value);

        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = user.Claims;

        var accId = claims.Where(x => x.Type == "AccountId").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accId))
          this.Account_id = Int32.Parse(accId);

        roles = claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(c => c.Value).ToList();


      }
    }
​
```

Comment: I'm seeing httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User as NULL

Comment: may be your startup.cs configuration is not completed 
see this link to detect configs:
https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/05/accessing-httpcontext-asp-net-core/

Comment: Your saying you can access User in your controller constructor? Seems to contradict what others are saying

Comment: whatever in a controller or in any C# file ...
you should be making the code inside the if statement to get the user info

this code I use in my projects

Answer (score 0):

To access User.Identity Claims in .Net core you need to use HttpContext. Here is my below implementation

First register

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

And then register in Service or Controller class

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public UserService(
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
            UserManager<User> userManager,
            SignInManager<User> signInManager,
            RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _currentUserGuid = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirst(UserClaimsKey.Sub)?.Value;
            _currentUserName = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;
            _currentUserEmail = _currentUserGuid == null ? "" : userManager.FindByIdAsync(_currentUserGuid)?.Result?.Email;
        }
```

The detail of the implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/Awesome-CMS-Core/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Helper/Services/UserService.cs)

Please let me know if you have any problem

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net Core v.2+ you don't have to inject HttpContext or something. Acces User just like this:

```
public IActionResult GetMe()
{
    return Ok(User.Identity.Name);
}
```

Comment: This will work in a controller method, since User has been defined. The question was about accessing the User member in the constructor, which is not available unless you use HttpContextAccessor, as shown in batressc's post.