# HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity..Name is empty in IIS working in VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .net core 2.2 web application where the Signin happens using the following code

```
  await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            authProperties);
```

The values of httpContextAccessor.httpContext.user.identity.name are retained properly for further requests and works in VS2017.

But on deploying to server with IIS the same code doesnt work and the values for httpContextAccessor.User.Identity.Name is returning empty.

Any idea what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can open IIS and:
1-Activate Windows Autentication;
2-Disable Anonymous Autentication.

[Place on IIS where is autentication configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYWD2.png)

[Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGGtu.png)

Comment: i have tried that before. if i do that i get the error "This page isn’t workingtest.bre.co.uk is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Also i have checked the Cookies tab. its not creating any Auth Cookies. I might be missing something very basic

Comment: When you use Windows Autentication mode, the IIS use the user credentials to access de fisical path, so, make sure that the folder in server is with permitions activeted.

Comment: I gave all Users on that server full access for the published folder. still the same problem. I can see the login page atleast if i disable windows authentication. but if i enable it I get "The page isnt working. currently unable to handle the request. http error 500"

Comment: Note: You tryed enable Windows Autentication and Disable Anonymous Autentication simultaneously?